# How can I get a reference from UIBarButtonItem to the containing navigationController?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am in a **barButtonItem handler** method, and I need the reference to the navigation controller. But I do **not have a stored reference** to **navigation controller**. Any idea?

```
#import "ReportViewController.h"
#import "CenterViewAnimationUtility.h"

@implementation ReportViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:[CenterViewAnimationUtility class] action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

//next file ..

#import "CenterViewAnimationUtility.h"

@implementation CenterViewAnimationUtility

+ (void)buttonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

    UINavigationController *navigationController = barButtonItem.//..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this method is in a view controller which is in the navigation controller you can simply do:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
```

Question - why is your button handler a class method? This solution only works if you make the button handler a proper instance method.

If you REALLY need the target to be a class method, you can get a reference to the view controller from the button's `target` property:

```
UIViewController *target = barButtonItem.target;
UINavigationController *navigationController = target.navigationController;
```

Update:

Based on the fact that in this case the button's target is not the view controller, this solution does not work.

Comment: I have a utility class that handles more UIBarButtonItems and NSButtons that are placed on different controllers. Unfortunatelly controllers have different types, i.e. UIViewController and UITableViewController, so I can place logic into a common class and therefor I put out logic into a utility class, but I need somehow the reference to the controller that owns control.

Comment: @János See the 2nd half of my answer.

Comment: The problem with the second solution, that target gives back the utility class, but that has nothing to do with the controller.

Comment: @János OK, I see what you are doing. You are correct, if something other than the view controller is the target, my solution doesn't work. Sadly, there is no way to get anything from the `UIBarButton`. It's not a view. It has no parent. There is no way to walk up the responder chain.

Comment: I thought a barButtonItem.superView.***.navigationController or some magic solution might exist.

Comment: @János No, `UIBarButtonItem` (nor `UIBarItem`) is not a `UIView`. It doesn't have a `superview` property.

Comment: Ohh ok thanks i am deleting my all comment as it is not related to this answer

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you're making it a class method because it is used on a variety of buttons from different view controllers?

If so, a work-around would be to have each button send a target/action message to a method within its own UIViewController, and then have that method call the common class method, passing the UINavigationController as a parameter.

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
[<classObject> buttonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem 
   fromNavigationcontroller:(UINavigationController *)navController;
```

You would obviously need to re-write the class method to accept the additional parameter:

```
    + (void)buttonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem 
      fromNavigationcontroller:(UINavigationController *)navController{
```